# Подключение файла с другого домена в модуль js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, модули

Здравствуйте у меня проблема в приложении на vue в веб компонент необходимо навесить виджет платежа. В соответствии с [документацией разработчика](https://developers.cloudpayments.ru/#platezhnyy-vidzhet), виджит подключается через тег script, но в модуле такой вариант не проходит (Failed to compile), пробую подключить через импорт но тоже не вариант

```
import "https://widget.cloudpayments.ru/bundles/cloudpayments";
```

в итоге прошу подсказать как можно подключить сторонний файл и использовать переменные из него

Comment: Ну дак вкрячте <script></script> в /public/index.html

Comment: @АлександрРогонов так и сделал) но это какой то глимый костыль)